# Using pytorch to predict the x-position of the fold in scanned bookpages

Tags: pytorch, dataset, artificial-intelligence

as stated in the title I want to use Pytorch to predict the x-position of the fold in scanned bookpages, I can use this information later on to split the page in the left and the right one.

Here is a sample image
[image]

How should I prepare the data and define the model for this case?

Could I use a csv file with the image names and the x-position as columns to train the model or should it work in a different way?

Also, the images are very large, what would be a good size to use here and what would be the minimum size of the dataset?

I tried already to create a csv file as follows

> image,fold_x
> img/jpg/smaller/dataset/0001_L.jpg,231
> img/jpg/smaller/dataset/0002_L.jpg,235
> img/jpg/smaller/dataset/0003_L.jpg,241
> img/jpg/smaller/dataset/0004_L.jpg,247
> img/jpg/smaller/dataset/0005_L.jpg,248
> ...

but I didn't get it to work.

Any ideas on how to start would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Wezy

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical regression problem.

What format the data is in does not matter much (except for how fast your training will be. Here are some tips to get you going:

1. Your label (x-position) is somewhere between the left and the right of the image. As such, it is clearly bounded. I would scale the label to be in range `[0,1]` and then translate that later to the exact pixel. This allows your model to converge much faster as you can simply use like a sigmoid function as a final-layer activation function (particularly because it is most often somewhere in the middle of the picture).
2. You probably want to use a convolutional neural network which decreases the image size very quickly to reduce all the complexity of your model. You won't need most of the data in your images, so compressing as quickly as possible will help you a ton in how fast you can train your model.
3. After the convolutional neural net, you will probably want a multi-layer perceptron.
4. Any blog post on regression using convolutional neural nets will probably help you very much to get started.
5. The biggest problem I see is image size. If you can, you can try to preprocess all your images by

   - Reducing the resolution.
   - Cropping images (you only need the middle).
   - removing the color (greyscale is much faster). Most of the info in your images is contrast, not color.
   - Loading all the images into objects before training (if that fits into your RAM). Preferably a PyTorch dataloader which just contains the tensors and labels.

Hopes this helps you get started.